# Mass picture upload to mediawiki

Tags: image, mediawiki

I'm working on a wiki supported by mediawiki and I was wondering if there were a way to do a mass upload of all the images and their descriptions (summary's) instead of one by one? I have a Google sheet with the image names and the description for each so maybe that helps? It would be even better if it could highlight all the images it uploaded successfully in the Google sheet. Thanks!

Comment: Would any of these help? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Bulk_upload

Comment: How is that related to programming, or are you aiming to write a custom batch-upload tool? (refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: There are many upload tools and you haven't really explained your specific use case so it's hard to tell which one would serve you best, but the most common and versatile one is probably [Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/upload.py).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your quick responses! Capricorn, I am completely new to programming (except for a brief intro in high school). What I am trying to do is to find or write a piece of code which will automate these things as follows. 1. Copy a file name in Google sheets. 2. Click on the upload file botton on my wiki. 3. Click on "choose file". 4. Paste the filename which should bring up the image. 5. Press ok. 6 go to the "file summary " box and select it. 6. Go back to the Google sheet and copy the description. 7. Go back to the wiki page and paste.

Comment: 8. Back to the sheet and copy the third cell in (reference line). 9. Go back to the wiki browser and paste one line under the description. 10. Press "upload file" 11.  if it works go back to the sheet and highlight all 3 cells in orange or if it didn't work highlight in blue. 12. Rinse and repeat. I dont know if this is possible or even where to begin but I thought I'd ask. I have approximately 900 images to upload which isn't the end of the world but I thought I would try to use this as a learning experience. Thanks in advance!